# В чём различие `var ... = ...` и `var ... := ...` в GDScript?

Tags: godot, gdscript

Есть такой код на GDScript:

```
var a := 5
```

И такой:

```
var a = 5
```

Оба кода при выполнении создадут переменную с именем `a` и значением `5`.

**Но в чём разница этих двух вариантов?**

Comment: Попробуйте потом изменить переменную в обоих случаях `a = "я не число"`

Comment: @andreymal о спасибо, действительно `:=` делает переменную с неизменяемым типом.

Comment: @andreymal можете написать ответ.

Comment: [Godot will try to infer types if you write a colon, but you omit the type](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/scripting/gdscript/static_typing.html#how-to-use-static-typing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Двоеточие задаёт тип переменной. Если тип не указан, Godot попытается его вывести автоматически из выражения:

```
var a := 5
# То же самое, что и
var a: int = 5
```

Заменить значение переменной на другой тип будет нельзя:

```
a = "я не int"
# Parse Error: Value of type "String" cannot be assigned to a variable of type "int".
```

Если двоеточие не указывать, то переменная получает тип [Variant](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_variant.html), что по сути означает, что значение может быть любого типа:

```
var a = 5
# То же самое, что и
var a: Variant = 5

a = "я не int, но я тоже Variant"  # Работает
```

Если значение является результатом вызова функции, то тип может быть выведен из возвращаемого значения, но только если в функции указан его тип:

```
func untyped():
    return 5

var a1 := untyped()  # Не работает
var a2: Variant = untyped()  # Работает

func typed() -> int:
    return 5

var a3 := typed()  # Работает (тип int)
var a4 = typed()  # Работает (тип Variant, потому что двоеточия нет)

func typed_variant() -> Variant:
    return 5

var a5 := typed_variant()  # Работает (тип Variant), но пишет предупреждение
var a6: Variant = typed_variant()  # Работает без предупреждений
```

Подробнее о статической типизации в документации: https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/scripting/gdscript/static_typing.html